# Spring Backend with Angular Frontend - how to update view when server changes

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I don't have much code yet because I first wanted to ask you about your opinion. Maybe you were already confronted with this issue and found a proper solution. So I just searched the Internet a little for now and found some proposals. My frontend is written with Angular 7 and the Backend is done with Spring.

**My problem looks like followed:**

I have a map that displays charging stations for electric vehicles. 
Charging stations can be either currently available then they will be shown with a green marker on the map. Otherwise they are unavailable and will be shown represented by a red marker on the map.

[image: Map with markers representing available (green) or unavailable (red) charging stations for eCars]

**What I want to achieve**

Imagine the map shown above is the map displayed to User-A. The charging station in the lower left corner is currently available and shown in green. When User-B reserves the charging station I want to update User-A´s map so the charging station on User-A´s map turns from *currently available/green* to *currently unavailable/ red*.

**What my code looks like**
Currently the charging stations are fetched once from the backend when the map is accessed for the first time. This is done in the **charging-station.service.js** file via a REST call to our backend API using the angular httpClient.

[image]

**What I already tried**

I already google a little bit and stumbled upon two approaches. The first one (that i kind of dislike) is active polling. You send a request every time interval to the server fetching the same charging-stations with potentially new availability status. The thing I dislike about this approach I am putting a lot of unnecessary workload on the backend.

The second approach if found was using web sockets. I never worked with them before. So I wanted to ask you what you, as potentially more experienced developers, would suppose me. Either approach 1, 2 or something completely different.

Comment: An additional solution would be SSE. Beware of WebSockets: they're cool, but often blocked by corporate firewalls. You can of course use a combination of those methods (like falling back to polling if websockets are unavailable). Some libraries do that natively.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I really appreciate that. It helps me a lot when people suppose possible technological solutions to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Pooling alone cannot be an effective solution for your problem, You should check SSE.
I suppose your messages will only flow from server to client. Web sockets are more useful when your messages are passed on both sides. And never forget that WebSocket comes with a lot of baggage. So if you decide to go with that, be ready to carry that.

Comment: SSE = Server-Sent Events if that helps someone searching